# Changing the signature of the metric and consecuences in the causal structure of the spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, causality

I was reading about the implications in the causal structure due to a change in the signature of the metric.

I know that if you choose a spacetime $(M,g_{ab})$. With $g_{ab}$ a Lorentzian metric, of signature  $(-,+,+,+)$, in  the Minkowski space time you can construct globally the causal structure of the spacetime, and that structure is given by the light cones.

With causal structure I mean that: If one event $q\in M$ can causal influence another event at the point $p\in M$, then $q$ is inside (or over) the past light cone of $p$.

However, if you choose another type of signature, for example $(-,-,+,+)$, and if you analize this "spacetime" you [can't  recover  the causal structure](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11544.pdf) because "It is not possible to distinguish a past from a future time-like direction and hence order events, even locally". But  I can't see why this happens. Can someone help me?

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Spacetime_dimensionality.svg

Comment: Really good Image, I would like to have more information.

Comment: Well I do not have more information ...I took from the wiki page about  anthropic principle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now have a closed curve (like a circle) in the timelike directions. Take a light-cone with 2 spatial dimensions, but now switch time and space by turning the cone so that time is now 2D and space 1D.

[image: robphy-rotated light cone]

The timelike axes are now t and y, and the spatial axis is just x.

Comment: I don't understand how to turn the cone.

Comment: I added a diagram.